# Lazy Evaluation in Forest Package?

Tags: environments, forest

I'm using the `forest` package to draw logic circuits, and I'm trying to customize the style. I want the inputs to be aligned, so I write this macro:

```
\newcommand{\inp}[1]{[#1,tier=in]}
```

But when the tree is evaluated, it doesn't recognize I'm trying to control the tree formatting programmatically, and interprets `\inp{x}` as part of the text of a node. Here's a minimal working example and the output:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\newcommand{\inp}[1]{[#1,tier=in]}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
[AND
  \inp{x}
    [OR
      \inp{y}
      \inp{z}
    ]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

The output is

[image]

The problem seems to be that the environment reads the structure without evaluating the `\inp{x}` commands; it doesn't see square brackets, so it registers as normal text to be put together with the preceding node.

But I want all of the `\inp{x}` to be evaluated first before the environment decides the structure of the tree. How can I do that?

Comment: Why do you want to use a command? Surely it would be easier to use a style?

Answer (score 6):

I recommend using a style instead. This way, you just add `, inp=<whatever>` to the relevant parent node.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt,multi,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
  \forestset{
    inp/.style={
      prepend={[#1, tier=in]},
    },
  }
  \begin{forest}
    [AND, inp=x
      [OR, inp=z, inp=y
      ]
    ]
  \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: forest tree]

## EDIT

If a command is really needed, you can do this, but you need to use `@+` before the start of the tree, and you should be aware that this alters the way `forest` parses the tree in fairly fundamental ways. So you cannot use much standard functionality without switching back to regular mode. Details of how to do this are in the manual. But you need to use `@-`. The following is adapted from the manual for `forest`. (Obviously.)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt,multi,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}

\newcommand\inp[1]{@@\edef\xtemp{@+[#1,tier=in]}\expandafter\bracketResume\xtemp}

\begin{document}
  \bracketset{action character=@}
  \begin{forest}
  @+[AND
    \inp{x}
      [OR
        \inp{y}
        \inp{z}
      ]
  ]
  \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This certainly is one option, but do you know how to make the original approach (with a command) to work? It's an expansion issue, but I haven't been able to find the solution yet.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Not with the desired syntax. Do you think that's possible? I mean, I can use action characters as shown in the manual, but then you need the action characters to actually occur in the relevant places in the tree. That seems to me much less intuitive and complex than using a style?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina See my edit. I realise this isn't what you had in mind, but it is the best I can come up with right now :(.

Comment: Ah, this is somehow closer to the "pure command" approach. I hadn't seen the use of `@+`, `@-` before. Thanks for introducing them to me! (can't up.vote more than once, though).

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Impure command approach... ;).